# Security questions from login with SESSIONS (PHPSESSID) or COOKIES if is same.. or not?

Tags: php, authentication, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have several questions about SESSIONS and COOKIES, I read in internet and all people recommend use SESSIONS (for security) but.. Not is same save the ID login in one session (phpsessid) that save in one cookie?

I tested this:

> I copied my PHPSESSID ID (cookie) from my login account from a website
>   ( in chrome) and insert my PHPSESSID (cookie) in another browser (in
>   opera) with VPN and I can access in this account.

What is the security here? if anyone can guess or hijack my cookie PHPSESSID ID is same if I use a Cookie to saving the login id, or not?

My question is.. Dont is more secure use a secure cookie ID like in wordpress, encrypting ID and checking in DB the IP and USER_AGENT ?

Now, I using this:
I create a random ID and save in one cookie (when the user login is success)
And check if this ID exist in the DB, check if the IP (saved in DB) and USER_AGENT (saved in DB) is equal. if not, login another time

Anyone can me guide a little? **Thx you** for read.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask yourself this: "How easy is it to guess the randomly generated random id?".

If your answer to this question is "very easy" you should make it harder to guess. Use a UUID or some other form of securely random ID.

If you answer is "quite hard" you should not have to worry about this. The only attack vector you are offering is to be able to guess a randomly generated id.

You can read more about "guessing the PHPSESSID" [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81519/session-hijacking-through-sessionid-brute-forcing-possible).

In general it should not be necessary to check the IPs of the user (as a side note, you open up yourself to all the stuff in the GDPR by doing this) or their User-Agent as both things might change during the sessions lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

The key point about sessions is that they are a **server-side** storage. In other words, your program writes whatever it sees fit and it reads back exactly what it wrote before because information cannot be tampered by clients as it happens with cookies. Additionally, the information remains hidden to client's eyes so it can store confidential or just internal uninteresting information. Last but not least, a PHP session allows to store most data types supported by PHP. A cookie can only store plain text.

The weak link in sessions is that HTTP is a stateless protocol so the client needs to identify itself on *every* request (unlike it happens in other network protocols as FTP, SSH or SMTP). Earlier implementations would transmit the session ID in the URL itself. It was later improved to only use cookies and cookies can be configured to be restricted to encrypted connections. But, yes, if something intercepts your HTTP traffic and finds out your session ID he can easily impersonate you because most sites don't care about implementing further checks. However, that's why HTTPS is encouraged nowadays.